# offset values not coming properly in angular directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css, jquery-animate, css-animations

I have something like this:

```
app.directive('mydirective', function() {
    angular.element.fn.animate = function() {
        try {
            console.log(this);
            var SrcElClone = this.clone();
            console.log(SrcElClone);
            var SrcElOffset = this.offset();
            console.log(SrcElOffset);
            SrcElClone.css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': SrcElOffset.top,
                'left': SrcElOffset.left,
                'opacity': 1,
                'z-index': 1000            
            }).animate({
                'top': 500,
                'left':500
            }, 2000).fadeOut({
                complete: function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                }
            });
            return;
        } catch (e) { console.log(e); }
    };
    function link(scope, element, attributes) {
        element.on(
                "click",
                function handleClickEvent( event ) {
                    element.animate();
                }
            );
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: link
    }
});
```

There is a ng-click also bound to my element which executes a method defined in the respective controller. If I remove ng-click directive, then I am able to get exact offset values in 'SrcElOffset' defined in my directive. However, if I also write ng-click within the element, then my offset values are coming as 0 always.
Am I doing anything wrong?